# Unable to access certain websites on ubuntu 20.04 after installing 20.04

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns

Some websites I can't access, I can't even access this website on my Ubuntu machine yet I can still access google, Youtube, itsfoss, etc. I can't go to the lutris website, or many others yet I can still access others. Currently, my Ethernet shows up with a question mark on it at the top of the screen for some reason.

I live in the US btw so isps blocking this type of stuff would be too unusual to be plausible.

Also, attempting to access these unaccessible websites brings me this error: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN